# contentOffset не работает

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть горизонтальная прокрутка в `webView`. Мне нужно чтобы текст в `webView` показывался не с самого начала, а с позиции `x = 1000`. Для этого я использую следующую строчку:

```
self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
```

Проблема в том, что она работает только в методе `scrollViewDidScroll`, а если я использую ее там, то после этого не могу прокручивать свой `webView` потому что он всегда на `x = 1000`

Во `viewDidLoad` строчка не работает. Где ее нужно прописать чтобы она работала при старте `webView`, а потом можно было нормально все прокручивать.

Полный код:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        webView?.scrollView.delegate = self
        
        do {
            guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html")
                else {
                    print ("File reading error")
                    return
            }
            
            let headerString = "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\" />"
            let string =  try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
            let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
            webView.loadHTMLString(headerString+string, baseURL: baseUrl)
            webView.scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
            
            self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x = 1000
        }
        catch {
            print ("File HTML error")
        }
    }

}
```

Этот вариант тоже не работает во `viewDidLoad`

```
webView.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задавайте `contentOffset` после загрузки данных. В методе [webView(_:didFinish:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview) делегата [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate) задавайте нужный:

```
...setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 0), animated: false)
```